# Ursina. Как удалить eternal объект

Tags: python, ursina

В документации у объектов `entity` есть параметр `eternal`:

```
eternal = False    # eternal entities does not get destroyed on scene.clear()
```

Однако помимо невозможности удалить их `scene.clear()` (чего я собственно я и хотел добиться), появилась и нежелательная невозможность удаления прямой командой `destroy(entity, delay=0)`.

Comment: А этот параметр `eternal` нельзя поменять у готового объекта? Ну, перед удалением.

Comment: @CrazyElf отличное решение. Но это все равно не позволяет удалить дочерние `eternal` объекты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from ursina.ursinastuff import _destroy
_destroy(entity, force_destroy=True)
```

удаляет в любом случае.
Сама функция `destroy()` изначально обращается к `_destroy()`, однако без ее конкретного импортирования в своем коде ее использовать не получится.

При этом не удаляет дочерние объекты, если они так же имеют параметр `eternal = True`